# Items won't move around JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

This is the code.

```
public class Main {
    public static int Health = 100;
    public static int ArmourPt = 0;
    public static int Gold = 250;
    public static JLabel Goldlbl = new JLabel("Gold:");
    public static JLabel Healthlbl = new JLabel("Health:");
    public static JLabel ArmourPtLbl = new JLabel("Armour Points");
    public static String GoldString = (Integer.toString(Gold));
    public static JLabel GoldDis = new JLabel(GoldString);
    public static String HealthString = (Integer.toString(Health));
    public static JLabel HealthDis = new JLabel(HealthString);
    public static JFrame MainWindow = new JFrame();

    public static int CalcDamage(int Damage, int Armour) {
        int ReturnDamage = Damage - Armour + Damage / Damage + Armour / Damage * Damage -         Armour + Damage + 25 ;
        if(ReturnDamage < 0){
            ReturnDamage = 0;
        }
        return ReturnDamage;     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainWindow.setSize(1500, 700);
        MainWindow.setTitle("Ampventure");;

        JPanel MPanel = (JPanel)MainWindow.getContentPane();
        MPanel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel StatsPanel = new JPanel();
        StatsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        StatsPanel.setSize(350, 450);
        StatsPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
        StatsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (350, 450));
        StatsPanel.add(Goldlbl);
        Goldlbl.setLocation(30, 14);
        StatsPanel.add(GoldDis);
        GoldDis.setLocation(35, 14);
        StatsPanel.add(Healthlbl);
        Healthlbl.setLocation(0, 0);
        MPanel.add(StatsPanel);

        JPanel InvPanel = new JPanel();
        InvPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        InvPanel.setSize(350, 212);
        InvPanel.setLocation(0, 450);
        StatsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (350, 250));
        MPanel.add(InvPanel);

        JPanel DisplayPanel = new JPanel();
        DisplayPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        DisplayPanel.setSize(1135, 450);
        DisplayPanel.setLocation(350, 0);
        MPanel.add(DisplayPanel);

        JPanel ControlPanel = new JPanel();
        ControlPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        ControlPanel.setSize(1135, 212);
        ControlPanel.setLocation(350, 450);
        MPanel.add(ControlPanel);

        MainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What is supposed to happen: A window divided into four sections and on the upper right section two labels named Gold: and Health: displayed with the first spaced above the second one.

What happens at execution: The label Health: is horizontally next to the label Gold:

I have tried changing everything, but nothing works.

Also I realize my program uses a null layout manager, but that is my intention. Not a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You set the null layout only for `MPanel`. Nested panels do not inherit parent's layout.  `StatsPanel` has `FlowLayout` as this is a default layout of `JPanel`. `Goldlbl` and `Healthlbl` are positioned according to the rules of `FlowLayout`. See [How to Use FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for more examples.

If the intention is to use absolute positioning then execute `StatsPanel.setLayout(null);`. In case of absolute layout you have to call `setbounds` method for each of the container's children. See [Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) for details.

As a side note, the naming convention of the posted snippet is a bit confusing. See Java [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).